# Python's ElementTree analog for Scala or JVM

Tags: xml, scala, jvm, lxml

ElementTree is the most interesting Python library I am using. 
Briefly, it is XML-parser with nice API, which stores XML-tree in memory (like Python objects) and gives the ability of both constructing and parsing.

Now I am looking for some JVM-compilant libruary doing similar.

What i have looked Scala XML for now, but it has very bad XPath support.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/basic-xml-processing-with-scala/

You may try using JOOX as well https://code.google.com/p/joox/